# jQuery stop Skrollr script

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I make a simple page with skrollr and I want when the size is smaller that 1200 when I resize the screen to stop the script.

```
var s = null;

if ($(window).width() >= 1200) {
    var s = skrollr.init();
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    viewportWidth = $(this).width();
    if ( viewportWidth > 1200 && w <= 1200){
        s = skrollr.init();
        w = viewportWidth;
    }else if (viewportWidth <= 1200 && w>1200) {
        s = // ???;
        w = viewportWidth;
    };
}).resize();
```

My problem is I don't know what I have to write when the viewport is smaller that 1200px.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like if the user resizes the window to smaller than 1200 pixels, you want to disable skrollr; if the user resizes the window larger than 1200 pixels, you want to enable skrollr. Here's one way to do that.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();

  if (width < 1200 && skrollr.get() === undefined) {
    skrollr.init();
  } else if (width >= 1200 && skrollr.get() !== undefined) {
    skrollr.destroy();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work ... Strange because in documentation is says:

Destroys skrollr. All class and style attributes will be set to the values they had before.

Comment: ok ... So a friend of me told me how to do it ... instead of skrollr.destroy(); I have to put skrollr.init().destroy();